# .NET objects not initiated from VB6 when server get converted to Windows 2008 R2 64-bit

Tags: .net, windows, vb6, createobject

We have very old and complex VB6 application that initiate .NET server objects, just like that CreateObject(sClassName, sServerName). It is sucesfully working in our production server. Now we are trying to move our production to Windows 2008 R2 64-bet machine, and that call not working anymore, no errors, nothing, it is just always returning empty string. Looks like our .NET object didn't get created.
All objects have GUID and ProgId, reristered in assembly and overal mimick whatever we have in production.
Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CreateObject can't be returning an empty string. It either [returns an object or raises an error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262700%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Maybe you're accidentally using an old version of the component? Put in some logging and check the TypeName of the returned object.

Are you ignoring errors with On Error Resume Next?

You could try explicitly targetting 32 bit when you build the .Net components, as the VB6 will only run as 32 bit.

Comment: No, I am sure about version of the component. VB6 runs just fine, and return data from other types of components. Looks like it is not creating object, not sure how to check why.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get an error Error Number:4100 Source:Microsoft ADO/RDS Description: Business object cannot be created. I am also check if objct get created with myObject is Nothing, it is returning False, so I believe it is actually created. An error appears when I try to call myObject.myFunction(), that is where it is failing.

Comment: Google suggests [checking some configuration settings on the new machine](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251122)

Comment: I tried that article, but it is not for IIS7, looks like it is important and make all difference.